# Angular paste picture from clipboard

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a functionality where users can paste a picture on the page son I can upload it to the server and show it to he user.

I'm aware of the paste event, and tried to implement from there but haven't been able to access any data from the clipboard from the event, either the files or items array from the clipboard field of the event are always empty when I press ctrl + v.

here's the code:

```
    <div (paste)="pastePicture($event)" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; background-color:#ccc;">
</div>

  pastePicture(event: ClipboardEvent) {
console.log(event);  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/QmELBtWJqjAuEwGPiCZh?p=preview

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all data from the event using property `event.clipboardData`.
For example, to get text data you can call:
`event.clipboardData.getData('text')`.
Also you can find properties: files, items and types which would help you to get more content.

Comment: I can't, from the tests I've done, and as you can see in the example I provided it only works for text, I just can't access picutres or files on the clipboard data. If you you can provide an example proving me wrong, that would be nice.

Comment: @dazzed When I copied the image and paste in your example in plunker, I got next object:
https://gyazo.com/3ac542dd7858ee4a59a39b95d523f9dc

Comment: That's interesting, because I always get files, items, types as empty arrays. Are you running on the latest version of Chrome? Thanks

Comment: @dazzed Yes, I'm.

Comment: Ok, I see that you paused the debugger and acessed the event through the dev tools console, it actually also worked for me, acessing the clipboard data from the console, although the object is empty when I access it on the pastePicture event and this is when I need it to have the data.

Comment: have you try this : `$event.clipboardData.files[0]` ? you can access to File object.